# Refactor scriptblock into different function from start-job

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to have the script block contained in a different function from the function that contains the start-job method?

What I am looking for is this:

```
function Get-jobA
{

   $params="data1,data2" 
   $jobs += Start-Job -ScriptBlock Get-MyScriptBlock -ArgumentList $params
}

function Get-MyScriptBlock
{
   [string]param1,[string]param2 = $args
   Start-Process -FilePath <someFile> -ArgumentList 'param1,param2' -PassThru -Wait

}
```

Answer (score 3):

A job has its own scope, so the function needs to be defined in it, before you can use it. You can use InitializationScript parameter to pass your function definitions inside the job, using the following syntax.

```
$functions = {
  function Get-MyScriptBlock
  {  
    return "Hello!";
  }
}

function Get-jobA
{   
  $job = Start-Job -InitializationScript $functions 
         -ScriptBlock { Get-MyScriptBlock } | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
  Write-Host $job;
}

Get-jobA
```

Answer (score 0):

The argument for `-ScriptBlock` must be a script block. Your function, however, does not return a script block, but the result of the `Start-Process` cmdlet. Change it to actually return a script block:

```
function Get-MyScriptBlock {
  return {
    Param([string]param1, [string]param2)
    Start-Process -FilePath <someFile> -ArgumentList $param1, $param2 `
      -PassThru -Wait
  }
}
```

and modify `Get-JobA` like this:

```
function Get-jobA {
  $params = "data1", "data2"
  $jobs += Start-Job -ScriptBlock (Get-MyScriptBlock) -ArgumentList $params
}
```

Note the parentheses around `Get-MyScriptBlock`. You need to execute the function in a subshell, otherwise PowerShell would interpret `-ArgumentList $params` as arguments of `Get-MyScriptBlock` instead of `Start-Job`. Also note that the argument list must be an array of two strings when your script block expects two string arguments.